# What did exactly happen to Saul Goodman in Breaking Bad?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I've watched the super hit TV series *Breaking Bad* and I have a question regarding one of the important characters in this series, **Saul Goodman**.

How did this lawyer die in the series? Did they show the death of this character in the Breaking Bad series? Which episode was this guy last seen?

Comment: You might want to watch the TV series called *Better Call Saul* and see him after the *Breaking Bad* events.

Comment: @SilverBebs You mean before right?

Comment: "How did this solicitor die in the series?"  Why do you think he died?  Did you watch Breaking Bad?   Have you not heard of Better Call Saul?  I don't understand!

Comment: @ThomasMoors, both: before and after :-)

Comment: I don't remember anything from breaking Bad that suggest Saul is dead.  What scene makes you think that he died?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He didn't die. As we see in the prequel series Better Call Saul, Saul left Albuquerque at the end of Breaking Bad, and is a fast food manager under the name "Gene".

Comment: Better yet, we see him leaving in pre-last episode, when he used that "clean slate" service about a week after Walter White did. He met Walter last time in a hideout below vacuum cleaner shop and left, said he don't want to do any business with Walter any more. Then Better Call Saul happens.

Comment: Another nod to the penultimate episode is the fact that he works at a Cinnabon. In the penultimate episode, Saul says words to the effect of "Now, the best I can hope for is to be a Manager of a Cinnabon"

Comment: @Mr better call Saul is mainly set as a prequel 6 years before breaking bad.

Comment: @cde: I like to think of it as a sequel that just happens to include one fairly long an extensive prequel-period flashback per season.

Answer (score 8):

[MULTIPLE SPOILER ALERT]

In the final season of Breaking Bad, when Walter is about to embark on his mission to free Jesse, Saul Says:

> "If I'm lucky, in a month from now, best-case scenario, I'm managing a
>   Cinnabon in Omaha."

Then at the beginning of the spin-off series Better Call Saul, you see Saul working in a Cinnabon, exactly as he described...

Every season in Better Call Saul opens with an eerie scene of Saul in his current state; miserable, hiding, but **alive** as of Season 3 which was recently released.